# How to make an image as big as the nav when the nav is automatically sized by font?

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have a `nav` bar, in which some links are provided. For ease's sake, I've only included one link in the code below. This navigation bar's height is automatically determined by the font-size used by the links. Now here's my problem: I want to add an `img` to the bar, that fills up the bar, however big it may get because of the links.

This is for a mobile website. Now I may be noob in this area, but I've noticed that smartphone browsers handle a website way differently than desktop browsers scaled down. Following that logic, I don't want to hardcode the size of the elements because it might scale weirdly on other devices. I want everything to be determined by one value, if possible.
I've read some things about `display: flex;` but truth is, I can't figure out how it works. I've tried setting the height of the `img` to `100%` but since the height of the `nav` is by default `auto` and thus set by the `font-size` of the links, that doesn't work.

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <img src="/include/img/logo/flame.svg" alt="info"/>
    <a href="">Link</a>
</nav>
```

CSS: (only positioning/scaling properties included, so no colors etc.)

```
nav {
    display: flex;
    padding-left: .5%;
    padding-right: .5%;
}
nav a {
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 4em;
}
```

I want it to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gcczd.png) (image height manually set in pixels)

But of course, it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huuEi.png) (sorry, can't post pictures yet)

(the image has some white space beneath it, which is 'to be fixed')

Any ideas? I can't be the only one who has ever had this issue.

Comment: You seem to understand the problem, i.e. that with a container that's sized ```auto```, the height of the child will not be constrained because the nav will grow to contain its content.  You can try altering the width and height of the SVG itself, but that's tantamount to setting it statically in pixels, which, to be honest, I don't see an issue with (just take a look at SO's logo, for example).  Flex box would not  address the issue of a container without set dimensions growing to fit larger children.

Comment: you can use javascript to get the height of the nav bar and set the height of your image.